# JavaScript - Code Working - But Don't Understand Logic

Tags: javascript, logic

[VS CODE + TERMINAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7ZLJ.png)

The code is as follows:

```
const bobsFollowers = ['John', 'Dan', 'Matt', 'Ted'];

const tinasFollowers = ['Sarah', 'Dan', 'Ted']; 

const mutualFollowers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++) {
for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++) {
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]) { 
        mutualFollowers.push([bobsFollowers[i]])
    }
}
}
```

console.log(mutualFollowers);

*** Just to be clear the code is functional. The names which are shared by both are then logged to the console successfully. This is a task taken from CodeAcademy. However, I understand all steps except for the final step where : "mutualFollowers.push([bobsFollowers[i]])" -- why is it that "bobsFollowers[i]" is now referring to the elements which both bobsFollowers and tinasFollowers share ?

I'm struggling to understand the logic of this. If anyone could explain this to me it would be greatly appreciated. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: _"why is it that "bobsFollowers[i]" is now referring to the elements which both bobsFollowers and tinasFollowers share ?"_ Because `if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j])`

Comment: using the bruteforce method in the `for {}` loop, you compare **each** value against each other. and if it matches, using method `push()`, you put these matched values into the originally empty array - `const mutualFollowers = [];`. after executing the code, this empty array will already contain values - `Dan` and `Ted`

Answer (score 0):

Because of the previous conditional
`if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j])` we can assume that they both share the same followers at their respective indexes, so in this case the code just goes with adding `bobsFollowers[i]` to the `mutualFollowers` array. The same would have been true if the code had used `tinasFollowers[j]`. :) Hope that helps!